# Surface of an onion-shaped church tower

Tags: geometry, surfaces

I am wondering how to calculate surface of the church tower in the picture, for painting purposes. Especially, I am interested in the two 'onion-shaped' parts.
I am thinking, that it is not really round, it consists of 6 equal parts, that are twisted, but would look like this on plane: like this:

```
  __
 /  \
/____\
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

[image: church tower]

Comment: For painting purposes? Use a sphere, add 20%, charge it to the client.

Comment: Dome... It's called dome. And the 6 equal parts being twisted is weird.

Comment: What do you mean by `'calculate the surface'`?

Comment: You need a parametrization !

Comment: @UserX what is wierd on it?

Comment: @Nick what does one need to do to find out the amount of paint necessary for painting? Calculate the surface of the area about to be painted?

Comment: @myro: As a painter myself, I see that logic as being absurd. Get enough paint to fill your canvas. Wait, do you mean that you wish to paint the church tower as opposed to painting a picture of the church tower          !           ?

Comment: The onion shapes are similar to [earthen pots](http://www.dsource.in/gallery/gallery-0235/fullview_image/3.jpg)

Comment: @Nick thats right. My canvas will be the roof itself :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*MATHEMATICAL ANSWER:*

Referring to the picture: let $\theta$ be the angle $B\widehat{A}P$, in your case $\theta=\pi/6$.

$f(h)$ describes the shape of an edge of the dome as a function of the height, i.e. $f(h)$ is the distance of the edge from the central axis of the dome evaluated at a ceratin height $h$. Let's suppose that you know $f$ and let's suppose that the height of the dome is $H$. The length of the segment $AP$ is given by $f(h)\cos\theta$, so the length of the curve $OP$ is given by
\begin{equation}
s(h)=\int_0^h\sqrt{1+(f'(t)\cos\theta)^2}\ dt
\end{equation}
If we know how to express $BP$ in terms of $s$, by the means of a function $g(s)$, then the surface area of the portion of the dome is
\begin{equation}
A=2\int_0^{s(H)}g(s)\ ds
\end{equation}
We know that $BP=f(h)\sin\theta$, and that $ds/dh=\sqrt{1+(f'(h)\cos\theta)^2}$, so in the end I guess that
\begin{equation}
A=2\int_0^Hf(h)\sin\theta\sqrt{1+(f'(h)\cos\theta)^2}\ dh
\end{equation}

[image]

*PRACTICAL ANSWER:*

as hinted in the comments, get a lot of paint (you will anyway use it for something else since you're a painter) and ask a for a lot of money (you can tell them you have to buy a lot of paint!)